# ArcPy/Python: How can I add a word into a string infront of a specific word of that string?

Tags: python, string, arcpy

I'm working with Arcpy to edit large shapefiles. I'm currently using the `UpdateCursor` function to find and update a type attribute based on the feature's name.  In this case, changing buoys into lighted buoys based on the words light, or lighted being in the features name.  The basic block I am using is as follows.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(navp,"""TYPEC = 'LATERAL BUOY' AND NAME LIKE'%Lighted%' OR NAME LIKE'%Light%'""")
for row in cursor:
    row.setValue('TYPEC',"LATERAL LIGHTED BUOY")
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The issue is I would have to do this for every type of buoy in my data.  I have over a dozen colors, lateral, and non lateral buoys to deal with.  I know I could repeat this block for each one of my cases and get a workable script, but that would be messy, and I'm trying to learn how to make my code more elegant, and efficient.  Are there any ways I could simply drop "LIGHTED" in front of `BUOY` for all features selected by
`cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(navp,"""TYPEC LIKE'%BUOY%' AND NAME LIKE'%Lighted%' OR NAME LIKE'%Light%'""")`??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can express the cases as a list of tuples, you can use a for loop over that list.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my own issue.  I just had to review my built in string formatting functions.  I used .replace() inside my .UpdateCursor for loop to find, and then replace the appropriate sub strings.  Here is my final code block.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(navp,"""TYPEC LIKE'%BUOY%' AND NAME LIKE'%Light%'""")
for row in cursor:
    row.setValue('TYPEC',row.getValue("TYPEC").replace("BUOY","LIGHTED BUOY"))
    cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
```

Short and sweet.  Thanks for looking!